# Multisite domain naming

Tags: multisite, hosting, domain-mapping, dns

i am new to wordpress multi-site. We are planning to have PaaS.

Internal subdomains i know can be possible to map. However can i use external subdomain via DNA (cname) to map?

for example

i know that subdomain.mydomain.com is possible but subdomain.notmydomain.com can be possible?

what can be the requirements/suggestions for such a setup in terms of hosting.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control of the DNS settings for "notmydomain.com", then sure. A subsite can be under a completely different domain if you want.

Comment: yes that's what i meant.i have less reputations but a big thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can make DNS entries for notmydomain.com it should be possible. You simply need to have whatever.notmydomain.com resolving to the same place as mydomain.com and then you only need to edit the site to use whatever.notmydomain.com. That's it.